# Fetch latest object for each user id from Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm, group-by, aggregate

I have a table with the schema:-

```
           Column       |         Type          |
     --------------------------------------------------------
     id                 | integer               | primary_key
     user_id            | integer               | not null
     total_properties   | integer               | not null
     created_at         | date                  | not null
```

The django model for this is:-

```
class User_Data(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    total_properties = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True, default=timezone.now)

    class Meta():
        app_label = 'users'
```

with data something like:-

```
      id   | user_id | total_properties | created_at
     --------------------------------------------------------
     1     | 100     | 4                | 2015-10-04
     2     | 101     | 11               | 2015-10-04
     3     | 103     | 7                | 2015-10-04
     4     | 100     | 6                | 2015-10-05
     5     | 103     | 12               | 2015-10-05
     6     | 105     | 1                | 2015-10-05
     7     | 100     | 13               | 2015-10-05
     8     | 106     | 14               | 2015-10-06
     9     | 103     | 40               | 2015-10-06
     10    | 109     | 3                | 2015-10-06
```

I want to fetch the latest (i.e for max `created_at`) `total_properties` for each `user_id`, i.e the following data:-

```
      id   | user_id | total_properties | created_at
     --------------------------------------------------------
     2     | 101     | 11               | 2015-10-04
     6     | 105     | 1                | 2015-10-05
     7     | 100     | 13               | 2015-10-05
     8     | 106     | 14               | 2015-10-06
     9     | 103     | 40               | 2015-10-06
     10    | 109     | 3                | 2015-10-06
```

Please guide how this can be achieved via Django Model class

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with dates (how it should handle the same dates for the same user id?). Can you just take ids instead smth like `.values('user_id').annotate(Max('id'))`.. ?

Comment: I am with @mariodev since id is an auto field it would be easier and more efficient to use that.

Comment: For each user and a date we have one or none entry

Comment: @nimeshkiranverma Then try my query with `created_at` instead of `id`.